# Multiple Syntax Use

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Please correct my SQL query for use in Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM GNGRB.PRBOOK 
WHERE (SERIES = 'I' AND BOOKNO = '180922') 
  AND (SERIES = 'J' AND BOOKNO = '138446')
  AND (SERIES = 'K' AND BOOKNO = '196491')
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are you not getting the results you want?  If so, provide a test case that shows the problem.  My guess is that you're not getting the results you want because it is impossible that any row would have a `series` value of I and J and K at the same time.  I'd guess that you want to `or` together your conditions rather than `and`ing them.

Comment: You want `OR`, not `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you use the OR between the brackets? I am not sure about the use case, but looks like there will never be result from the query, as you are expecting multiple value in same column at same time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM GNGRB.PRBOOK 
WHERE (SERIES = 'I' AND BOOKNO = '180922') 
   OR (SERIES = 'J' AND BOOKNO = '138446') 
   OR (SERIES = 'K' AND BOOKNO = '196491')
```

Answer (score 3):

I got you. You want all records which have either of mentioned combinations.

As mentioned in other answer, use `OR` or you can use the `IN` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM GNGRB.PRBOOK
WHERE (SERIES,BOOKNO) IN (('I','180922'), ('J', '138446'), ('K',  '196491'))
```